# "Export to Excel" with an excel template possible?

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to use the "Export to Excel" functionality. But as I see its only possible to export the data and do some (colour) formating of the cloumns/ cells.
But not any fancy excel functions.

Is it possible to use an existing excel template and fill only one sheet with the data. And on the other, already exsiting, sheets we have some fancy diagrams with links to the sheet, which we want to fill with the "export".

Is this possible. And if yes how? 
Didn't find anything about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear if you want to use the function on a chart, grid, map... 
Assuming its a Grid:
You can, invoking the saveAsExcel method from the client API  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/saveasexcel

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/saveasexcel#saveasexcel

The telerik example

```
$("#export").click(function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.saveAsExcel();
});
```

I suggest to create a object with all the data you need to export instead of using the grid element.

Comment: No not on a grid. Just as a stand alone feature.
Creating some data and exporting it.
Like here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/


And instead of creating a new Excel sheet I wnat to use a template sheet and just put the data in a sheet. On the other, already existing sheets, we have some charts which links to these data.